# Is there a Git config setting to auto-signed-off-by my commits?

Tags: git-commit

In some repos I want to always include "signed-off-by" messages in my commits (`git commit -s` not `git commit -S` which is for a cryptographic signature). Is there a `.gitconfig` value I can set to make this happen (so I can just type `git commit` instead of `git commit -s` every time)?